# Render turning black after rendering Blender 3.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

New to blender, former MAYA user.

Even Though I have fallen in love with Blender so far, I am having a very unsettling time when it comes to rendering.

My render looks just normal, and at the very end of the process, when it reaches 100%, it goes dim to almost black (I say almost because there's a glimmer where the most intense part of the light is). I've checked the solutions here but they are for previous Blender versions, and, I tried what those answers said, but it didn't solved my issue. So, hopefully there's a guru outthere who can help me out. I'll add a few images of my settings and issue.

Thank you beforehand!

Edit: I'll just label what the images are:

1. Mid render screen shot
2. Finished render
3. Compositing settings
4. Render Settings, Film exposure

[image: Mid render screen capture]

[image: Render finished]

[image: Compositing settings]

[image: Render settings, Film exposure]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the *Mix* factor in the *Glare* node in the compositor. From the [Glare node documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/glare.html):

> **Mix**
>
> Value to control how much of the effect is added on to the image. A value of -1 would give just the original image, 0 gives a 50/50 mix, and 1 gives just the effect.

Currently the *Mix* value is set to 1. Setting it to 0 will solve the issue.

Comment: You've saved me man, thanks alot! This instantly solved the issue.